# loading modules by imp.load_source with same name resulting merger of the modules

Tags: python

I would like to know if the following behavior is expected or a bug.  I'm using CPython2.7

Create a file x.py

```
def funcA():
    print "funcA of x.py"
def funcB():
    print "funcB of x.py"
```

Create a file y.py

```
def funcB():
    print "funcB of y.py"
```

Create a file test.py

```
import sys, imp
# load x.py as fff
m = imp.load_source('fff', 'x.py')
print dir(m)
print sys.modules.get('fff')
# load y.py as fff
m = imp.load_source('fff', 'y.py')
print dir(m)    
print sys.modules.get('fff')

# import and exec func
import fff
fff.funcA()
fff.funcB()
print dir(fff)
```

The result

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'funcA', 'funcB']
<module 'fff' from 'x.py'>
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'funcA', 'funcB']
<module 'fff' from 'y.py'>
funcA of x.py
funcB of y.py
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'funcA', 'funcB']
```

My expectation was that the 2nd `imp.load_source` would completely replace the module x.py with y.py.  In fact `sys.modules.get('fff')` shows `<module 'fff' from 'y.py'>` but the resulting module was like a mix of x.py and y.py, and the latter has the precedence.

Is this expected or a bug?

EDIT: my test code had a typo. updated the result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an expected behavior.
See http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html

> imp.load_source(name, pathname[, file])
>
> > Load and initialize a module implemented as a Python source file and return its module object. If the module was already initialized, it will be initialized again. The name argument is used to create or **access** a module object.

Since your second module has the same name as the first module, it won't replace the first one, but will be merged into the first one.

The source code gives us the same answer.
`imp` is a built-in module, defined in [import.c](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/import.c). 
Let's look at at the definition of `load_source`

```
static PyObject *
load_source_module(char *name, char *pathname, FILE *fp)
{
    ......
    m = PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx(name, (PyObject *)co, pathname);
    Py_DECREF(co);

    return m;
}
```

It's just a wrapper for `PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx`.

```
PyObject *
PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx(char *name, PyObject *co, char *pathname)
{
    PyObject *modules = PyImport_GetModuleDict();
    PyObject *m, *d, *v;

    m = PyImport_AddModule(name);
    ......
    d = PyModule_GetDict(m);
    ......
    v = PyEval_EvalCode((PyCodeObject *)co, d, d);
    ......
}
```

Now, we just need to focus on `PyImport_AddModule`. Python uses it to obtain a module object. Your parsed source file will be put into this module object.

```
PyObject *
PyImport_AddModule(const char *name)
{
    PyObject *modules = PyImport_GetModuleDict();
    PyObject *m;

    if ((m = PyDict_GetItemString(modules, name)) != NULL &&
        PyModule_Check(m))
        return m;
    m = PyModule_New(name);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (PyDict_SetItemString(modules, name, m) != 0) {
        Py_DECREF(m);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_DECREF(m); /* Yes, it still exists, in modules! */

    return m;
}
```

Finally, we find the answer. Given a `name`, if some module already has this `name`, namely, `name in sys.modules`, Python won't create a new module, but will reuse that module.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking all the way into import.c. I wonder what's the good use case of this.  The document could be more explicit about the merger.   Other functions in the same module such as `load_module` and `reload` has a much better documentation.

Comment: Is there a way that the modules are not merged but replaced?

Comment: yes, always `del sys.modules['name of the module']` before imp.load_source.