# Load Python source/binary without adding to sys.modules

Tags: python, dynamic, import, module

I want to load Python code (if possible with an arbitrary file-extension or even from memory, source or binary) without adding it to `sys.modules`. Using `imp.load_source` works for loading a file but the returned module is added to `sys.modules` and might even be joined with an existing module (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082857/loading-modules-by-imp-load-source-with-same-name-resulting-merger-of-the-module))!

So, what I'm currently doing is using the `__import__()` built-in. Although it allows me to import from a package, I can not load an arbitrary file.

```
try:
    m = __import__(name)
    for n in name.split('.')[1:]:
        m = getattr(m, n)
    return m
except:
    raise
finally:
    # Restore the old module configuration. Only modules that have
    # not been in sys.path before will be removed.
    for k, v in sys.modules.items():
        if k not in prev_modules and self.is_local(v) or not v:
            del sys.modules[k]
        else:
            sys.modules[k] = v
```

1. Removing all modules that haven't been in before the import is a very hacky approach to me.
2. When a module with the name already exists, it is not reloaded.
3. I can not load an arbitrary file or even from memory.

I am trying to avoid the `exec` statement because of security reasons. The source evaluated by `exec` could hack in to my application using `sys._getframe()` (and there sure are many more possibilities to do). I have looked at the implementation of the django `load` tag, but that just uses `__import_()` as well.

Is there a way to load Python code (either source or binary) from a file (or even memory) that is secure, self-contained (no adding interaction with `sys.modules`)? In the best case, it would not only allow me to load a file and from memory, but also load a complete package like the `__import__()` function.

Comment: I think the word `secure` and `self-contained` is an impossible combination here. AFAIK, importing a python module effectively executes it. The closest thing I know is https://seattle.cs.washington.edu/browser/seattle/branches/repy_v2/repy/safe.py, which is attempts to build a safe exec. It's based on statically analyzing the code and removing access to 'dangerous' built-in's.

Comment: I just created a first GitHub gist related to loading command-line scripts as modules. The code could be modified to skip storing the module in sys.modules. https://gist.github.com/DanielMGessel/f92bf80e199e23e2a250567980e0bf8e

Comment: You might want to take a look at [localimport](https://pypi.org/project/localimport/). (Disclaimer: I am the author of this package)

Answer (score 1):

Using the CPython interpreter, I don't believe this is possible. However, PyPy provides a sandboxed environment that makes what you want to do quite easy.

[Look at the PyPy documentation on sandboxing for details.](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html)