# Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

How can I import an arbitrary python source file (whose filename could contain any characters, and does not always ends with `.py`) in **Python 3.3+**?

I used [`imp.load_module`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.load_module) as follows:

```
>>> import imp
>>> path = '/tmp/a-b.txt'
>>> with open(path, 'U') as f:
...     mod = imp.load_module('a_b', f, path, ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE))
...
>>> mod
<module 'a_b' from '/tmp/a-b.txt'>
```

It still works in Python 3.3, but according to `imp.load_module` documentation, it is deprecated:

> *Deprecated since version 3.3*: Unneeded as loaders should be used to
>   load modules and find_module() is deprecated.

and `imp` module documentation recommends to use `importlib`:

> **Note** New programs should use importlib rather than this module.

What is the proper way to load an arbitrary python source file in Python 3.3+ without using the deprecated `imp.load_module` function?

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing this? I'm the maintainer of importlib and I have been trying to get answers from folks as to why they use `imp.load_module()` over a straight import statement. Do you expect to import the module by name later (e.g. `import a_b`)? Do you care that any custom importers won't be used in this approach? Do you expect the module to be full-featured (e.g. define `__name__` and `__loader__`)?

Comment: @BrettCannon, A third-party program regularly (once a hour) modify a text file that contains python statements (mainly `THIS='blah'` like lines). The name of the file is not ended with `.py`. My program read that file.

Comment: @BrettCannon, I'm not aware of custom importers. I don't care the module to be full-featured.

Comment: IOW using Python as a really simple data structure format. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @downvoter, Could you explain why?

Comment: @BrettCannon — I just ran into a case where I needed to import some Python code from within a directory which was named as a version number (e.g., "v1.0.2").  While possible, it would be highly undesirable to rename the directory.  I wound up using stefan-scherfke's solution below.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension/56090741#56090741

Comment: @BrettCannon: [Enaml](https://github.com/nucleic/enaml) is a use-case where one needs to use a different extension (in this case, `*.enaml`). Enaml is a superset of Python that allows for declarative markup (useful for creating responsive GUIs). Enaml runs with Python and has it's own import hooks (e.g., `enaml.import_hooks`) to allow for loading Enaml files in Python programs. Importing Enaml files typically requires doing so within an Enaml context manager (e.g., `with enaml.imports(): import ...`). However, sometimes we want to use `importlib` to load from an arbitrary Enaml source file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a python module without the .py extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension)

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功, Answers there mostly focused on python 2.x solution (imp), but I wanted solution that works Python 3.3+. Answers there that solve my question come after my own answer. (2013 vs 2016,2017,2019) [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19011259/2225682) answered my question.

Comment: It's true, retracted.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Found a solution from [`importlib` test code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/39d87b5/Lib/test/test_importlib/source/test_file_loader.py#L75).

Using [importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader):

```
>>> import importlib.machinery
>>> loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('a_b', '/tmp/a-b.txt')
>>> mod = loader.load_module()
>>> mod
<module 'a_b' from '/tmp/a-b.txt'>
```

**NOTE**: only works in *Python 3.3+*.

**UPDATE** [`Loader.load_module`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Loader.load_module) is deprecated since Python 3.4. Use [`Loader.exec_module`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Loader.exec_module) instead:

```
>>> import types
>>> import importlib.machinery
>>> loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('a_b', '/tmp/a-b.txt')
>>> mod = types.ModuleType(loader.name)
>>> loader.exec_module(mod)
>>> mod
<module 'a_b'>
```

---

```
>>> import importlib.machinery
>>> import importlib.util
>>> loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('a_b', '/tmp/a-b.txt')
>>> spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
>>> mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
>>> loader.exec_module(mod)
>>> mod
<module 'a_b' from '/tmp/a-b.txt'>
```

Comment: Downvoter: How can I improve the answer? If you have a better way to accomplish what I want, please let me know.

Comment: There's a helpful warning that `load_module` ignores via `warnings.catch_warnings`. If you instead use `mod = imp.load_source('a_b', '/tmp/a-b.txt')`, it raises the following warning (use `-Wall`): `DeprecationWarning: imp.load_source() is deprecated; use importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(name, pathname).load_module() instead`.

Comment: @eryksun, You're right. Thank you for the comment. BTW, Python 3.4(rc1) does not display the alternative usage unlike Python 3.3.x.

Comment: What's the difference between the first and the second example at the bottom?

Comment: @MatthewD.Scholefield ways to get module objects are different. Using Module type directly or using utility.

Comment: @falsetru - great work. Would be good to add that `SourceFileLoader` only understands pure Python source modules. For loading extension modules (.so / .dll files) with an arbitrary suffix, the sibling class `ExtensionFileLoader` is the way to go :)

Comment: Howto pass arguments in module constructor?

Comment: @e-info128 What is module constructor?

Comment: @falsetru I know this deviates a little from OP's question but, what if I have a (for example) class implementation that is held inside a string instead of in a file. Ex: `my_class =  """class Test: def __init__(self): self.x = 5 def print_number(self): print(self.x)"""` Is there a way to programmatically import this class inside the string to the  namespace?

Comment: @ihavenoidea, Please post a separated question, so that others can answer you, and other users can also read answers.

Comment: @falsetru In fact I have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009309/dynamically-import-module-from-memory-in-python-3-using-hooks), no answer so far. I posted here in the comments because I bumped into your answer after posting my question. If you know how to do this, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I can't get this to load the source code from a class. Can you help me with my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67663614/11343425 ? Thanks

Comment: How do I pass all the constants, methods and classes from **mod** to the main scope? I tried `from mod import *` but obviously didn't work.

Comment: @YoomarXD, `mod['name_you_want_access']`

Comment: @falsetru I meant to pass _mod.constant1_, _mod.method2_, etc. to the global scope simulating the behavior of `from foo import *`.
But nvm, already managed to archive it by:
`for key, val in [p for p in mod.__dict__.items() if not p[0].startswith('__')]:
    globals()[key] = val`

Comment: @YoomarXD, `globals().update({key: value for key, value in vars(mod).items() if not key.startswith('__')})`, BTW, I don't recommend to pollute module namespace at runtime.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to temporarily import plugin files to run. Does this code have any side effects, i.e. caching in sys.modules? As near as I can tell, no, but can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 46):

#### Updated for Python >= 3.8:

Short version:

```
>>> # https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly
>>> import importlib.util, sys
>>> spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(modname, fname)
>>> module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
>>> sys.modules[modname] = module
>>> spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Full version:

```
>>> import importlib.util
>>> import sys
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
>>> 
>>> 
>>> if TYPE_CHECKING:
...     import types
...
...
>>> def import_source_file(fname: str | Path, modname: str) -> "types.ModuleType":
...     """
...     Import a Python source file and return the loaded module.

...     Args:
...         fname: The full path to the source file.  It may container characters like `.`
...             or `-`.
...         modname: The name for the loaded module.  It may contain `.` and even characters
...             that would normally not be allowed (e.g., `-`).
...     Return:
...         The imported module

...     Raises:
...         ImportError: If the file cannot be imported (e.g, if it's not a `.py` file or if
...             it does not exist).
...         Exception: Any exception that is raised while executing the module (e.g.,
...             :exc:`SyntaxError).  These are errors made by the author of the module!
...     """
...     # https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly
...     spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(modname, fname)
...     if spec is None:
...         raise ImportError(f"Could not load spec for module '{modname}' at: {fname}")
...     module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
...     sys.modules[modname] = module
...     try:
...         spec.loader.exec_module(module)
...     except FileNotFoundError as e:
...         raise ImportError(f"{e.strerror}: {fname}") from e
...     return module
...
>>> import_source_file(Path("/tmp/my_mod.py"), "my_mod")
<module 'my_mod' from '/tmp/my_mod.py'>
```

#### Original answer for Python 3.5 and 3.6

Shorter version of @falsetru 's solution:

```
>>> import importlib.util
>>> spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('a_b', '/tmp/a-b.py')
>>> mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
>>> spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
>>> mod
<module 'a_b' from '/tmp/a-b.txt'>
```

I tested it with Python 3.5 and 3.6.

According to the comments, it does not work with arbitrary file extensions.

Comment: `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(..)` returns `None` for me; causing an exception for the following `importlib.util.module_from_spec(..)` call. (See https://i.imgur.com/ZjyFhif.png)

Comment: `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location` works for known file name extensions (`.py`, `.so`, ..), but not for others (`.txt`...)

Comment: Oh, I’m using it only with Python files but modified my example to look like the one above and did not test it … I updated it.

Answer (score 16):

Similar to @falsetru but for **Python 3.5+** and accounting for what [the `importlib` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.module_from_spec) states on using `importlib.util.module_from_spec` over `types.ModuleType`:

> This function [`importlib.util.module_from_spec`] is preferred over using `types.ModuleType` to create a new
>   module as spec is used to set as many import-controlled attributes on
>   the module as possible.

We are able to import any file with `importlib` alone by modifying the `importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES` list.

```py
import importlib

importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES.append('') # empty string to allow any file
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
# if desired: importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES.pop()
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, while this hack of appending the empty string to the list of source suffixes works great for importing renamed Python source modules, the equivalent for importing renamed extension modules does not work... That is, using `importlib.machinery.EXTENSION_SUFFIXES.append('')` still makes `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location` return None.

Comment: presumably, `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location` should still work with extensions if you specify a loader

Comment: @mxxk that's because, if you look at the source, it's only checking if the suffix is present for files named `__init__`

Answer (score 6):

**`importlib` helper function**

Here is a convenient, ready-to-use helper to replace `imp`, with an example. The technique is the same as that of https://stackoverflow.com/a/19011259/895245 , this is just providing a more convenient function.

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import importlib

def import_path(path):
    module_name = os.path.basename(path).replace('-', '_')
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(
        module_name,
        importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(module_name, path)
    )
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    return module

notmain = import_path('not-main')
print(notmain)
print(notmain.x)
```

not-main

```
x = 1
```

Run:

```
python3 main.py
```

Output:

```
<module 'not_main' from 'not-main'>
1
```

I replace `-` with `_` because my importable Python executables without extension have hyphens as in `my-cmd`. This is not mandatory, but produces better module names like `my_cmd`.

This pattern is also mentioned in the docs at: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly

I ended up moving to it because after updating to Python 3.7, `import imp` prints:

```
DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
```

and I don't know how to turn that off, this was asked at:

- [The imp module is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596204/the-imp-module-is-deprecated)
- [How to ignore deprecation warnings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python)

Related:

- [How can I import a module dynamically given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-the-full-path)

Tested in Python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

after many failure solutions this one works for me

```
def _import(func,*args):
    import os
    from importlib import util
    module_name = "my_module"
    BASE_DIR = "wanted module directory path"
    path =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,module_name)
    spec = util.spec_from_file_location(func, path)
    mod = util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
    return getattr(mod,func)(*args)
```

and to call it just write the function name and it's parameters `_import("function",*args)`