# How do I write Python unit tests for scripts in my bin directory

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

The Python `unittest` module seems to assume a directory structure for a project in which there's a project root level directory with the source code and tests under that directory.

I would like, however, to write Python scripts in my `~/bin` directory and tests for it in another directory (say, `~/dev/tests`). Is there a way for me to run the unit tests using the command line interface without setting my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and creating `__init__.py` files and whatnot?

Here's a simple example demonstrating what I want:

`~/bin/candy`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def candy():
    return "candy"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print candy()
```

`~/dev/tests/test_candy.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import candy

class CandyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def testCandy(self):
        candyOutput = candy.candy()

        assert candyOutput == "candy"
```

I notice that everything can be done conveniently if:

- The two files are named with py extensions (`candy.py` and `test_candy.py`)
- The two files are in the same directory
- The test is run with the following in the directory of the tests:
  $ python -m unittest test_candy

Can I run python with the `unittest` module to do the following without setting anything in my environment explicitly:

- My file under test does not have the py extension (just `~/candy`).
- I don't care if `test_candy` has py as an extension or not.
- I want `candy` and `test_candy.py` to not share a common root (other than my home directory).

If that's not possible with a simple invocation of `python -m unittest`, what is the most simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you writing python files without a `.py` extension?

Comment: Modules in a python library should have the .py extension.  Executable scripts, on the other hand, be they shell, perl, python, or whatever, don't need .ksh, .bash, .py, etc. extensions because the user of them doesn't need to know how what language they are implemented in to run them.  I generally don't name executables with an extension indicating the type of script it is.

Comment: It's pretty easy to do this for adhoc tests, just use `imp.load_source(MODULE_NAME, 'bin/EXECUTABLE_FILE')`, what I find I'm having trouble with is when doing debuild, it's not copying files that don't end in .py to the build dir so those scripts don't get tested in the build

Comment: @PeterTurner can you elaborate a bit more? What kind of build are you performing? If it's the `distutils`/`setuptools` build, then the scripts passed via `scripts` list to the `setup` function are copied to `build/scripts-X.Y`, where X.Y is the interpreter version.

Comment: @hoefling, oh, I don't have a "scripts" list I'll have to look that up, I'm just doing a debuild with some parameters, can't remember off-hand, I'll look it up Monday

Answer (score 11):

This is candy executable (no change):

```
➜ cat ~/bin/candy

#!/usr/bin/env python    
def candy():
  return "candy"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print candy()
```

and this is `~/dev/tests/test_candy.py` (changed):

```
➜ cat ~/dev/tests/test_candy.py

#!/usr/bin/env python

import imp
import unittest

from os.path import expanduser, join

# use expanduser to locate its home dir and join bin and candy module paths
candy_module_path =  join(expanduser("~"), "bin", "candy")

# load the module without .py extension
candy = imp.load_source("candy", candy_module_path)


class CandyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def testCandy(self):
        candyOutput = candy.candy()

        assert candyOutput == "candy"
```

What changed?

- We added `imp.load_source` to import `~/bin/candy` (a module without `*.py` extension)
- We added provision to locate home directory mention i.e. `~` using `expanduser`
- We are using `os.path.join` to join the paths for `~/bin/candy`

Now you can run the tests with `discover` option of `unittest` module.

Check `python -m unittest --help` for more details.

Excerpts below

`-s directory     Directory to start discovery ('.' default)`

`-p pattern       Pattern to match test files ('test*.py' default)`

```
➜ python -m unittest discover -s ~/bin/ -p 'test*' -v ~/dev/tests
testCandy (test_candy.CandyTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Python 3.3 the `imp` package has been deprecated and the `importlib` package replaces it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3) gives details of how to import a single file.

For your unit test, this would be:

```py
from importlib.machinery import ModuleSpec, SourceFileLoader
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
import os.path
import types
import unittest


def import_from_source( name : str, file_path : str ) -> types.ModuleType:
    loader : SourceFileLoader = SourceFileLoader(name, file_path)
    spec : ModuleSpec = spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
    module : types.ModuleType = module_from_spec(spec)
    loader.exec_module(module)
    return module

script_path : str = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "..", "..", "bin", "candy",
    )
)

candy : types.ModuleType = import_from_source("candy", script_path)


class CandyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def testCandy(self : "CandyTestCase" ) -> None:
        self.assertEqual( candy.candy(), "candy" )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Assuming that the file structure is:

```
base_directory/bin/candy
base_directory/dev/tests/test_candy.py
```

*(Note: this unit test assumes a fixed relative path from the test rather than a fixed absolute path so that you can move the package to another directory and the test will not break so long as the files within the package do not change relative positions.)*

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this with unittest, but my quick fix for problems like these are to just change my working directory inside the script using the os module. This SHOULD work for you though.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import os
os.chdir("/usr/bin/candy")
import candy

class CandyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def testCandy(self):
        candyOutput = candy.candy()

        assert candyOutput == "candy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. The problem is that you need to import the modules you're trying to test, so at least you have to change your PYTHONPATH. My advice is that you change it temporarily as you execute the tests, like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend(['~/dir1','~/dir2','~/anotherdir'])
```

The solution of @Paritosh_Singh is algo good.

The long run is to install a test runner like **tox** and configure it so it "sees" your modules. But I think you don't want to do that.