# Should executable Python script be named with .py?

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python script that is only meant to be run from the console. e.g.: `$> myscript`.

I'm wondering what is the leading conventions in Python for scripts of this sort. Should I call it `myscript`, or `myscript.py`?

Comment: It's always good to add the .py extension. It's just a good convention that is expected by pretty much everyone.

Comment: One of python's virtues is easy code reuse.  If you will ever want to import that script into another script, then it needs to end with `.py`.

Comment: If you run the script with `python filename`, the suffix doesn't matter. But if you use `import modulename` to import it into another script, it expects the `.py` suffixx.

Comment: One thing you might consider is naming your script myscript.py and then making a soft link to it named myscript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

Why?

### Portability

Python scripts in Linux environments are recognized as such, but NT is... special. If there's ever a need to move it to anything made by microsoft, you need the extension.

### Readability

Appending a filename extension to it will make it obvious what kind of file it is, for when others look in your directories.

### Useability

If ever you need to call it into python as a module, you NEED the .py extension.

### Convention

It is the standard for all python scripts to have the .py or .pyc extension on them.