# Python: Importing arbitrarily named source files using importlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib, python-3.7, imp

I use the `imp` module to import Python modules from source, given the absolute filename. I.e.

```
import imp
my_module = imp.load_source('my_module', '/paht/to/my_module')
```

Here, `/paht/to/my_module` is the full path to a file containing Python source code, even though it does not have a `.py` extension.

When doing `import imp` in Python 3.7, the following deprecation warning is shown:

> DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses

I am thus in search for an `importlib` replacement of the `imp.load_source` function. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly), I have the following:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('my_module', '/paht/to/my_module')
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

This does not work when the filename has no extension, as in my case. I guess it fails because none of the implemented "finders" recognize the file as a Python source file. However, I do not really need all the complicated machinery provided by these finders, as I know for sure the absolute path to the file already. I simply want it imported.

A simple hack would be to just read in the source as text and execute it manually in its own namespace, something like

```
my_module = {} 
exec(open('/paht/to/my_module').read(), my_module)
```

(with this, names defined in `my_module` is available through `my_module['name']` rather than `my_module.name`, but you get the idea). I would like to know the proper way of doing this, using `importlib`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution to a similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3). Translated to my example:

```
import importlib.machinery, importlib.util
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('my_module', '/path/to/my_module')
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
my_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
loader.exec_module(my_module)
```