# Fetch __version__ value from file without using imp.load_source?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have previously done the following to fetch a version string:

```
>>> filepath = './somemodule/__init__.py'
>>> name = 'dummy'
>>> module_source = imp.load_source(name, filepath)
>>> module_source.__version__
1.0.0
```

Now, when `imp` has been deprecated in Python 3 (I'm on 3.7.1), what would be a nice replacement for `load_source` which will just require the std library?

This seems a little convoluted to me AND `load_module` is actually deprecated:

```
>>> from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
>>> loaded = SourceFileLoader(name, filepath).load_module()
>>> loaded.__version__
1.0.0
```

#### EDIT #1:

This is discussed in [Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3) and one of the solutions which came up there is:

```
>>> loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(name, filepath)
>>> mod = types.ModuleType(loader.name)
>>> loader.exec_module(mod)
>>> mod.__version__
1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The "comfortable" way to import a module is to use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).  This is, for all practical purposes, just like using the `import` statement.  However, it cannot import arbitrary files which are not in `sys.path`, so it doesn't work for your use case.

To import a file directly, the `importlib` documentation [provides](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly) this recipe:

> ```
> import importlib.util
> import sys
>
> # For illustrative purposes.
> import tokenize
> file_path = tokenize.__file__
> module_name = tokenize.__name__
>
> spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
> module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
> spec.loader.exec_module(module)
> # Optional; only necessary if you want to be able to import the module
> # by name later.
> sys.modules[module_name] = module
> ```

Finally, a bit of advice: I recommend putting the version string in a separate text file called (say) `__version__.txt`, and loading it from `__init__.py` and anything else which needs to know the version.  That way, you don't need to execute Python code to read the version number.  You can load data from such files by using [`pkgutil.get_data(__package__, '__version__.txt')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) in `__init__.py`, and replace `__package__` with a suitable value when calling from another module, or open the file directly.  `get_data()` returns `bytes`; you may want to call [`.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) on the return value to convert it into a string.

(`pkgutil.get_data()` may seem a roundabout way to do it, but it's required if your code is [imported from a ZIP file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html) or installed in some other exotic way.  If your code is in a [namespace package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-namespace-package) or was installed in a particularly unusual fashion, `get_data()` may fail to work and return `None`, so you should check for that case and avoid crashing on it.)