# Loading Module in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error when I load the module in `Python 3.6`.

```
   spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(load_module,path)
   mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
   spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
```

I get the below error:

```
mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>",
line 568, in module_from_spec AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

How do I do it in the right way?

In the past, I have been using:

```
mod = importlib.import_module(load_module)
```

with the path of modules in the path. This works for `python 3.7`

Answer (score 2):

so you can import a module programatically like so:

```
my_module = importlib.import_module('my_module')
```

To specify a custom path you can use:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

If you're getting the error below, it means that `spec_from_file_location` couldn't locate the module and path you specified and returned `None`.

```
in module_from_spec AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Comment: Using `importlib.machinery` is an alternative which worked for me pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19011259/5308983