# is there a python function that will run other .py files with varying filenames

Tags: python

Is there a python command that will essentially perform the following?

```
for i in range(0, length):
    IndShort[i].test_function()
```

Trying to open a number of .py files, or rather, run test_function from a number of .py files (all existing, named IndShort1, IndShort2 ...).

I don't know that there is any further information that I might provide

```
for i in range(0, length):
    IndShort[i].test_function()
```

Perhaps too general of a question to expect any specific results?

Comment: I think that your direct question is a request for dynamic `import` use.  However, if your purpose is to run a test quite, then you should look into existing test support packages.  Start with PyTest and UnitTest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `importlib` to import modules dynamically.

```
for i in range(0, length):
    mod = importlib.import_module("IndShort{}".format(i))
    mod.test_function()
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this worked perfectly (after importing importlib). Thanks so much!