# Dynamically import two files into another file in python which those two files are in the dufferent directories

Tags: python

I am trying to import the modules dynamically using python. My directory structure is

root_folder1:
-sub_folder1
-sub_folder2
---sub_sub_folder
-my_file1.py
-my_file2.py
-my_main_file.py

I have to import my_file1.py and my_file2.py(which is inside sub_Sub_folder) methods into my_main_file.py(inside the root_folder1). I am running my_main_file.py in the root_folder only.

To dynamically import those two file I tried using importlib and **import**. But I got an error 'no module named "

My code in my_main_file.py is:

```
import os, fnmatch
from pathlib import Path
import importlib
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))


listoffiles = os.listdir("sub_folder2/sub_sub_folder/")
pattern = "*.py"

abs_path = "sub_folder2/sub_sub_folder/"
for entry in listoffiles:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
        print(entry,abs_path)

        try:
            spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(entry, abs_path)
            print(spec)
            foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
            spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
            print(f'fp:{foo}{spec}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'The error is {e}')
```

i tried using the importlib.import_module(entry,package=abs_path). I got an error.

When I run the above code I am getting "The error is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'".

My question is:
How do I dynmaically import the files my_file1.py,my_file2.py into my_main_file.py and uses the fucntions of my_file1 and my_file2.

I tried [Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3) and I am getting no module error

Comment: you can do import sub_folder_2.sub_sub_folder.my_file1 in python3

Comment: I wanted to do dynamically.

Comment: I think see what you are doing wrong now. `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location` expects the path (second argument) to lead to the .py file you're trying to import, so you want something like `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(entry.strip('.py'), abs_path + entry)`

Comment: Hi sinback, Thanks after adding abs_path+entry the answer I am getting here is ModuleSpec(name='filename', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLo
ader object at 0x01DC6DB0>, origin='../../6bc61c4637e2_.py') <clas
s '_frozen_importlib.ModuleSpec'>. But the next two lines are not getting executed foo= importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo) , I hope module can be imported if I dont gett any error in these two lines. am I correct?