# How do I import a python file through a path?

Tags: python, linux, windows, directory

I am trying to make it so when this runs it runs the newest version in the list.

Here is the directory I want:

```
ClockOS:
   bootLoader.py (the file I am starting at)
   Versions:
      Version 0.1.1:
         main.py (Ignore because tis an older version)
      Version 0.1.2:
         main.py (The one I want to run/import)
```

---

I have tried loading  through `os.dir`, and using `sys.path`, and adding an empty `__init__.py`
Anyone know how to get this working?
My code:

```py
import os
import re
import sys

versionList = []

for filename in os.listdir('Versions'):
    if filename.startswith('Version'):
        versionList.append(filename)
        print(f"Loaded {filename}")

def major_minor_micro(version):
    major, minor, micro = re.search('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', version).groups()

    return int(major), int(minor), int(micro)

latest = str(max(versionList, key=major_minor_micro))

print("Newest Version: ", latest)

os.path.dirname('Versions/'+str(latest))


sys.path.insert(1, latest)
print(sys.path)



import main
```

Lastly, I need this to work on both windows and linix, if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `importlib` to do what you want. Here is an example on how to import `my_function` from a file:

```py
import importlib
    
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('some_module_name', filename)
mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
mod.my_function(1)
```

Probably the question is a duplicate of [Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)