# How to import a function and use it from a separate python script with PyQt5?

Tags: python, function, import, pyqt5

I'm working on a project that wraps `scipy.odr` with (hopefully) a simple GUI using `PyQt5`.
As the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) demands the `Model` class accepts functions which are defined **precisely** as such:

```
def linear_fit(a, x):
    return a[0] * x + a[1]
```

(A parametrs vector as the first argument and the free variable `x` as the second)

My intention is that the user will write a separate python script containing exactly one function, like the one defined above, **without** the need to define it inside the GUI python script (which I write and don't want the user to touch).

It is easy enough to make the user load the script with `PyQt5` `QFileDialog` and get the absolute path to the script with a function like this one:

```
def browsefiles(self):
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', 'C:', 'Python Script (*.py)')
    self.lineEdit_path.setText(fname[0])
    self.script_path = fname[0]
```

Next I want another button which when pressed will execute the fitting procedure as described in the documentation.
What I can't figure out is how to pass the function that the user wrote to the `Model` class inside the script where I wrote the GUI.

I can't import the user's script at the begining of the file because I don't know where the user saved his script before she loaded it using the GUI, and I can't even specify the function name because the user may call her function however she likes.

I would love some help solving this problem.

My GUI looks something like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import scipy.odr as odr


class FitGUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FitGUI, self).__init__()
        loadUi('fitgui.ui', self)

        self.pushButton_browse.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles)  # The function that I wrote above

        self.pushButton_fit.clicked.connect(self.fit)

        self.show()

    def fit(self):
        model = odr.Model(...)  # Here I want to pass the function that the user defined in a separate script
        ...  # The rest of the fitting procedure as described in the documentation

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = FitGUI()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you can use module `importlib` to load other module ising string with name. But for function's name it would be simpler if every user would use the same name. And this is how all plugins work - they always have to use the same names.

Answer (score 0):

After the comment from [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) I researched a bit and quickly found out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41595552/15031141) by [Stefan Scherfke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3564517/stefan-scherfke)
in a similar post, and used his function inside my GUI script.

Thank you.